# Increasing value by 1 continues forever

Tags: java, android, if-statement, increment

So, I have been working on this code for way to long for one day.  I am sure there has to be a simple way to solve this but I can't think anything right now.  First a small section of the code:

```
        if(Settings.totalHits >= 50 && Settings.totalHits <= 99)
        {
           Settings.medal1 = true;
           Settings.save(game.getFileIO());
           totalMedals = totalMedals + 1;
        }
```

This is a very basic achievement/medal system.  Basically, once the user has done a total of 50 hits, it sets the value of "medal1" to true, which will remove the "lock" image which only displays when medal1 = false.

The issue deals with the totalMedals section.  Basically, there is a total of 32 medals a user can earn, and after one is unlocked, it needs to update the totalMedals by 1.  So in this case, the output would be "1/32".  Except, now after the medal is unlocked (by hitting 50), the lock image is removed correctly, but the totalMedals keeps increasing by 1 extremely fast instead of just increasing to "1" and stopping.

Like I said, there has to be something small that I am overlooking here.  I tried tossing into a for loop but that didn't work (or I did it wrong).  Any idea what I can change to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to unlock the medal if you've reached the threshold *and* you haven't already unlocked it (the upper limit is irrelevant here), so you can use:

```
if (Settings.totalHits >= 50 && !Settings.medal1) {
    Settings.medal1 = true;
    Settings.save(game.getFileIO());
    totalMedals++;
}

if (Settings.totalHits >= 100 && !Settings.medal2) {
    Settings.medal2 = true;
    Settings.save(game.getFileIO());
    totalMedals++;
}

// and so on.
```

Though of course, this positively calls out for refactoring so as to efficiently use arrays, something like:

```
for (i = 1; i < 33; i++) {
    if (Settings.totalHits >= 50 * i && !Settings.medal[i-1]) {
        Settings.medal[i-1] = true;
        Settings.save(game.getFileIO());
        totalMedals++;
    }
}
```

And, if the thresholds aren't a direct multiple of 50, you can easily place an arbitrarily complex function (or array lookup) into the `if` statement to match your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
if(Settings.totalHits >= 50 && Settings.totalHits <= 99)
```

Try:

```
if(Settings.totalHits >= 50 && Settings.totalHits <= 99 && !Settings.medal1)
```

This way, once the medal has been triggered, it cannot be triggered again. Thus, `totalMedals` is only incremented once.